# Why getting 404 error for the api's on remote server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, deployment, iis-7

I have a ASP.Net WebApi project. I have deployed this on my local machine IIS.

On my local machine the api are runnning fine. Henceforth, I copied this set of file from my local machine to remote machine.

But while accessing the API's from remote machine, I am getting 404 Errors for all the apis.

I cross checked the IIS configuration on the machine. They are all same.

**Local IIS**

[image: Local IIS]

[image: Local App Pool]

**Remote IIS**

[image: Remote IIS]

[image: Remote Config]

http://localmachine/api/user/customer - On local running fine.

http://remotemachine/api/user/customer - on remote Http 404 error.

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: First only browse remote machine to check if it is accessible like `http://remotemachine`

Comment: @Mairaj, default index.html is loading fine

Comment: OK load the api main page.i.e without `controller/action`

Comment: @Mairaj Sorry!! I didn't get you

Comment: `http://remotemachine/api`

Comment: @Mairaj, same error

Comment: It means you have some other name of web api ?

Comment: In left pane what name are you seeing ?

Comment: @Mairaj But same set of deployed api is running fine on my local..

Comment: Name can make a difference can you show screenshot of IIS of remote machine of left pane ?

Comment: @Mairaj, please check this . http://prntscr.com/e9st1g

Comment: Is seems you have some name behind `api` browse with that name like 'myapi` or what ever is behind api so browse with complete name or just right click on webapi node and select Mange -> Browse

Comment: @Mairaj, same error

Comment: See detailed error looks like you have some missing extensions which needs to be installed.

Comment: @Mairaj, this is the error screen http://prnt.sc/e9sx6m

Comment: plz post your webconfig.xml

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, web.config https://codepaste.net/nrvt4n

Comment: maybe rry to put in your webconfig in the module ... <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, Yes. it fixed the issue. a big thanks :)

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Please post your comment as ans so that I can mark accepted & hope it help other

Comment: sure!!..thnx if you rate it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to  put in your `webconfig` in the module section...

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
<remove name="WebDAVModule"/> 
<remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
</modules>
```